# text is empty then it should display error

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display error msg in label form in jQuery. I have a dropdown with two values:

1. SERIAL_BASED and
2. BATCH_BASED

If user selects `SERIAL_BASED` and one is textField, id is 'txtSerialNumber' if it's empty, then it show display error msg not an alert dialog

Similarly, if user selects `BATCH_BASED` and textField id is 'txtBatchId' if it's empty, then it show display error msg not an alert dialog

[image]

I have one field for error display

```
<asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" runat="server" Style="color: Red;" CssClass="form-label"></asp:Label>

$("#MainContent_cmbStkMangOption").change(function () {
        var cmbStkMangOption = $("#MainContent_cmbStkMangOption").val();      
        var num = 0;

        if (cmbStkMangOption == "SERIAL_BASED") {
            if ($.trim($('#txtSerialNumber').val()) == '') {
                
            }
        }

        if (cmbStkMangOption == "BATCH_BASED") {
            if ($.trim($('#txtBatchId').val()) == '') {
                
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$("#lblErrorMsg").text("error message")`

Comment: Try this way `$("#<%= lblErrorMsg.ClientID %>").text("error message")`. @Barmar As it is `asp` control OP need to use `<%= lblErrorMsg.ClientID %>`.